# PHP Associative Arrays Use

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm currently learning PHP (beginner to programming) and am stuck trying to find a solution for the following basic problem...

It's a "bomb defuse" game with the following rules applying to only the next wire cut:

*If you cut a white cable you can't cut white or black cable.
If you cut a red cable you have to cut a green one
If you cut a black cable it is not allowed to cut a white, green or orange one
If you cut a orange cable you should cut a red or black one
If you cut a green one you have to cut a orange or white one
If you cut a purple cable you can't cut a purple, green, orange or white cable*

An input would be as follows...

*white, red, green, white*

So I arranged this data into an associative array with valid next cuts. I turned the input string into an array. How can I use this associative array to check if the next wire cut in the input array is a valid cut?

```
function bombDefuseValidation($inputString) {

    $input = $inputString;

    $inputExplodedArray = explode(", ", $input);

    //$inputExplodedArray = array('white', 'red', 'green', 'white');

    $inputExplodedArrayLength = count($inputExplodedArray);

    //Valid next cuts
    $rules = array(
        "white" => "red, green, orange, purple",
        "red" => "green", 
        "black" => "red, purple, black",
        "orange" => "red, black",
        "green" => "orange, white",
        "purple" => "red, black"
    );

}

bombDefuseValidation('white, red, green, white');
```

I need a way to take the inputs, such as 'white', check if the following input ('red') exists as a value in the 'white' key of the associative array, if it does, move on to the next input and keep checking. If they all match up to a value in the corresponding key, the bomb is defused. If one doesnt, "BOOM".

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why use those comma-delimited lists when you can use arrays instead?

Comment: Obviously, you need to loop through $inputString to check them in sequence. I might define a function checkCut($lastCut, $thisCut) which returns TRUE or FALSE based on whether the cut is allowed by your $rules array.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Sammitch... Yes, that makes more sense now that I thought about it. Just me being new to programming and being silly, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Array()`, it would be much easier!

```
function bombDefuseValidation($inputArray) {


    $inputExplodedArrayLength = count($inputArray);

    //Valid next cuts
    $rules = array(
        "white" => array("red", "green", "orange", "purple"),
        "red" => array("green"), 
        "black" => array("red", "purple", "black"),
        "orange" => array("red", "black"),
        "green" => array("orange", "white"),
        "purple" => array("red", "black")
    );

    for ($i = 0; $i < $inputExplodedArrayLength-1 ; $i++) {

    $temp = $rules[$inputArray[$i]];
    if(!in_array($inputArray[$i+1], $temp)) {

        $num = $i + 2;
        print("Invalid Input no. {$num}");
        return -1;
        }
    }

    print("Valid Input");
    return 0;

}


bombDefuseValidation(Array('white', 'red', 'green', 'white'));
```

Comment: This solution worked great after changing the for loop to: 

for ($i = 0; $i < ($inputExplodedArrayLength-1); $i++) { }

Thank you so much!